# Setting up a trigger to trigger when a specific cell is edited

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to transfer data from one Google sheet to another Google sheet based on when someone selects their name in a drop down box attached to that cell. The function is selecting the data I would like transferred from the source sheet to the destination sheet. When I run the function within the apps script it functions correctly, but when I tried adding a onEdit trigger it would pick up a range of cells instead of just one specific cell to trigger off of. Also I will have several cells that will have a drop down box attached to them and would have to have a trigger attached to that specific cell when edited.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

This is what I have come up with so far.

```js
function Submit_C4() {
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Fx4IQtx41Ck1yxjcDPzSGFgf9XAemX6MCjXD67S1qoI'); //SOURCE SHEET ID
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('sheet1'); //SOURCE SHEET NAME
 var range1 = ss.getRange(4,3,1); //PACKER NAME
 var range2 = ss.getRange(2,2,1); //CUSTOMER NAME
 var range3 = ss.getRange(4,2,1); //CASE
 var data1 = range1.getValues(); //PACKER NAME VALUE
 var data2 = range2.getValues(); //CUSTOMER NAME VALUE
 var data3 = range3.getValues(); //CASE VALUE
 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ePKc9q43jiGqMjygK71f8imIGOOlnr2_1jx1Q1Yiwf8'); //DESTINATION SHEET ID
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('sheet2'); //DESTINATION SHEET NAME
 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1,1,1,1).setValue(new Date()); //ADDS TODAY'S DATE
 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow(), 2,1,1).setValues(data2);
 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow(), 3,1,1).setValues(data1);
 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow(), 4,1,1).setValue(1);
 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow(), 5,1,1).setValues(data3); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### If you want your trigger to fire only when a specific cell is edited - you need to implement it into an conditional statement

- Apps script trigger feature [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- The `onEdit` trigger returns you the event object `range` which allows you to retrieve which range is being edited.
- To access event object you need to pass the event object as a funciton parameter, so you can retrieve the subparamters within your function

Sample:

```js
// provided your function is bound to an installable onEdit trigger, you can leave the name as it is, 
//but pass an event parameter to it
function Submit_C4(event) {
 var cellNotation = event.range.getA1Notation();
 var cellOfInterest = "A1";
 if (cellNotation == cellOfInterest){
  //do what you want
  }
  else{
  // do someting different or nothing
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight from google apps script documentation, [here's a link to simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) you should set it up like this

```
function onEdit() {
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Fx4IQtx41Ck1yxjcDPzSGFgf9XAemX6MCjXD67S1qoI'); //SOURCE SHEET ID
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('sheet1'); //SOURCE SHEET NAME
 var range1 = ss.getRange(4,3,1); //PACKER NAME
 var range2 = ss.getRange(2,2,1); //CUSTOMER NAME
 var range3 = ss.getRange(4,2,1); //CASE
 var data1 = range1.getValues(); //PACKER NAME VALUE
 var data2 = range2.getValues(); //CUSTOMER NAME VALUE
 var data3 = range3.getValues(); //CASE VALUE
 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ePKc9q43jiGqMjygK71f8imIGOOlnr2_1jx1Q1Yiwf8'); //DESTINATION SHEET ID
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('sheet2'); //DESTINATION SHEET NAME
 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1,1,1,1).setValue(new Date()); //ADDS TODAY'S DATE
 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow(), 2,1,1).setValues(data2);
 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow(), 3,1,1).setValues(data1);
 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow(), 4,1,1).setValue(1);
 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow(), 5,1,1).setValues(data3); 
}
```

please note the change of the function to `onEdit()` you will also need some form of `range` to select multiple cells

for the range I used two links, [1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) and [2](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) here's what i came up with:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var cell =  sheet.getCurrentCell();
```